# why does the replaceAll method adds more elements than I actually have?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm learning jquery and I have come across the replaceAll method. From my understanding, the replaceAll method removes a targeted selector with another element or selector. I created a simple example that had several h4 tags and each one of them has a different class with a different color. And when you click on the button, the blue class is supposed to replace the red class. It works, but I get more blue headers than I need. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdca27vz/)

HTML

```
<button>replaceAll</button>

<div id="ex1"><h2>Example 1</h2><p></p>
<h4 class="red">This is a header</h4>
<h4 class="blue">This is a header</h4>
<h4 class="green">This is a header</h4>
<h4 class="blue">This is a header</h4>
<h4 class="green">This is a header</h4>
<h4 class="red">This is a header</h4>
<h4 class="red">This is a header</h4>
<h4 class="red">This is a header</h4>
<h4 class="red">This is a header</h4>
<h4 class="blue">This is a header</h4>
<h4 class="green">This is a header</h4>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.red{color:red;}
.blue{color:blue;}
.green{color:green;}
```

JQuery

```
$('button').click(function(){

$('.blue').replaceAll('.red');

});
```

Comment: Did you read [the doco](http://api.jquery.com/replaceall/)? The method will "Replace each target element with the set of matched elements." in your case *the set of matched elements* includes *three* blue items...

Comment: See my answer for class manipulation, from what you have put that is what you want to achieve. Other answers and your own implementation is object over object manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replaceAll works as follows:

Select all `.blue` elements (total 3).

Finds first `.red` and replaces it with all 3 selected `.blue` divs.

Continues to next `.red` and repeats it.

You need to select only one `.blue` (I selected first one with `:first`):

```js
$('button').click(function() {

  $('.blue:first').replaceAll('.red');

});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>replaceAll</button>

<div id="ex1">
  <h2>Example 1</h2>
  <p></p>
  <h4 class="red">This is a header</h4>
  <h4 class="blue">This is a header</h4>
  <h4 class="green">This is a header</h4>
  <h4 class="blue">This is a header</h4>
  <h4 class="green">This is a header</h4>
  <h4 class="red">This is a header</h4>
  <h4 class="red">This is a header</h4>
  <h4 class="red">This is a header</h4>
  <h4 class="red">This is a header</h4>
  <h4 class="blue">This is a header</h4>
  <h4 class="green">This is a header</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: OP wants to replace just class of object, not object itself therefore this is a bad method of doing it. If the red header for example had the text 'hello world' and the blue header had 'world hello'... The innerHTML contents would also be replace.

Comment: @JokerDan And where do you read that? OP states that he found `replaceAll` and understands, that it will replace itself with other element (including content).

Comment: Here I will quote OP for you:
>"And when you click on the button, the blue class is supposed to replace the red class. It works, but I get more blue headers than I need. Here is the jsfiddle" -- Also your solution actually removes a header completely. See my answer.

Comment: @JokerDan Yes, OP says that he replaces element and that is what he wants, just with duplicates as side effect...

Comment: @JokerDan - the OP seems to be using "blue class" to refer to the element that has the blue class, not just to the class itself. (It's a little confusing and ambiguous, but I've seen other questions here from a number of different people who do the same.)

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$('.blue')` matches three `<h4 class="blue">` elements.

So each `$('.red')` will be replaced with three `<h4 class="blue">`.

What you want is :

```
$('<h4 class="blue">This is a header</h4>').replaceAll('.red');
```

Comment: Editing HTML structure of `.red` will require JS code adjustment too. Not best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In your current implementation you are selecting all objects based on if they have the class 'blue' and replacing them with all objects that have the class red. So each blue object gets replaced with x amount of objects selected based on having the .red class.

Change your Jquery button click to as follows;

```
$('button').click(function(){

    $('.blue').removeClass('blue').addClass('red');

});
```

This selecting all of the objects with class .blue, then removing the .blue class and adding the .red class.

Edit:
See your updated [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/fdca27vz/2/)